# HP N54L crashes during FreeNas boot - hardware diagnostics?

Tags: hp-proliant

My HP N54L has suddenly starting to crash during it's FreeNAS boot up cycle. I've not been able to get any help from the FreeNAS forums about logging the actual command that causes the crash.

Basically, the system boots fine, detects all hardware/RAM correctly, then midway through it's boot cycle the OS crashes, with what I call "white lines of death" on the monitor.

I then take the same USB boot stick onto another PC (e.g. a N40L) and it boots fine. This tells me it's not the FreeNAS OS that's at fault, it's the hardware.

As another test, I've also tried installing Windows Server 2012 R2 on the box and it locks up too early in the install process.

What I don't really know is how to diagnose the N54L to find out what hardware on it could be causing the glitch. I've tried removing the disks and replacing the RAM as obvious ones. I'm guessing it's not the CPU or power supply as it does actually start up.

Has anyone any advice?

Thanks